# What are the criterias to chose 32-64bit server?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, 32bit-64bit, central-processing-unit

My VPS hosting service allow me to install both Ubuntu 32bit and 64bit.

I need to install Apache, Mysql and Drupal on my server. I was wondering if I should go with 64bit and why ?

more in general

1) Is 32-64bit choice going to create software incompatibility issues ?

2) I thought the choice should depend on the machine architecture. Is that correct ? If yes, does this mean they are asking me what kind of processor I want to use ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the main benefits of Windows 64-bit over 32-bit?](http://serverfault.com/questions/37340/what-are-the-main-benefits-of-windows-64-bit-over-32-bit)

Comment: Yes, I know the other question specifies Windows. It's the closest one I could find. If you just search for "32-bit 64-bit" you'll see this has been answered many times over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None. There is NO (!) sense today to install a 32 bit server. 32 bit will lock you into a total reinstall if you need more memory etc. - applications are another thing (makes quite often sense to run them 32 bit), but the OS should never be 32 bit.

Comment: 32 bit system consule less memory. If growth over 3 Gb not planned.

Comment: @mmv - I keep hearing people say that a 64-bit OS consumes more memory and citing that as an excuse to stick with 32-bit... and I keep not seeing the point. Unless you're running a machine with 256Mb of RAM it's not going to make a difference.

Comment: It's worth noting that vendors of a lot of server products are slowly moving to 64-bit only. A 32-bit server will limit your options when you look at upgrading to newer versions of some of your software.

Comment: Same here. I am totaly 64 btit, client and server, for years. But then, I have VM's with gigabytes of memory because they need it.

Answer (score 1):

Need for a larger (3GB+) address space, availability of 32-/64-bit versions of software, and (for i386 vs. x86_64) use of larger register count for e.g. multimedia or scientific purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As TomTom said, why shouldn't you choose a 64-bit server... The services/applications you list will work on a 64-bit version of Ubuntu...